# Steering wheel became tight but Power steering pump not making noise

Tags: ford, steering, f-150

Recently my 2010 f150 xlt 4.6 truck steering wheel became tight at time but at other times it turns normal. The power steering pump isn't making a noise, has fluid and the belt isn't loose I cant think of a reason that it is doing this

Comment: Could be a problem with the rack or with the steering coupler. Can you hook a pressure gauge up to the power steering pump and confirm pressure?

Comment: Not at the moment I don't  have a pressure gauge so I'll have to go get one tomorrow